# Singular values and the chromatic number

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

What relation, if any, is there between the singular values of the adjacency matrix ( or possibly incidence matrix) of a simple graph and its chromatic number. Typically, do we have Hoffmann type, or Szekeres-Wilf type bounds? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: SVD for symmetric matrices is the same as the eigenvalue decomposition. So I would say there's nothing new.

Comment: @LeechLattice ok, but what about the SVD of incidence matrices? Anything new?

Comment: For a graph $G$, the singular values of its incidence matrix are the eigenvalues of its line graph added by $2$, with $|E(G)|-|V(G)|$ zeros removed.

Comment: @LeechLattice great! any proof of the fact ?